# Content Security Policy causes CSS to disappear

Tags: css, content-security-policy

If I add a Content Security Policy header to my application, the CSS stops working and the startup page does not display properly, including loss of images. Removal of the Content Security Policy header makes the page display correctly. No errors are received - the page simply does not display properly.

If I simply add Content Security Policy header with default-src having any value - including * - the application no longer uses the CSS. I've tried all possible values for default-src, and I've tried including values for style-src as well.

Here is the relevant web.config section. I've tried many different values, but this latest one should theoretically not block anything...

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.MYDOMAIN; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.MYDOMAIN; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.MYDOMAIN; img-src 'self'  https://*.MYDOMAIN; connect-src 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN; font-src 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN; object-src 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN; media-src 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN; child-src 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN; form-action 'self' https://*.MYDOMAIN; frame-ancestors 'self'" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

DevTools does not report any error except one which occurs without the CSP in place, and which also occurs when the application is properly running. So, the CSP does not introduce any new errors or messages different from normal operation.

I would expect Content Security Policy to have no effect on the CSS.

Comment: What's the exact error message that the browser logs in the devtools console?

Comment: No error message is logged by DevTools (except one which is logged when there is no CSP and the application runs normally). So, the introduction of CSP and the display problem does not produce any additional errors. Simply adding the CSP header causes CSS to be ignored. I will add this one interesting note: The problem only occurs when deployed to a server. I can get it to work on my local machine, but ONLY if I supply the unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval values.

Comment: CSP by default blocks inline styles (e.g. `<div style="text-align: center;">`) and afaik, also `<style>/*css here */</style>` styles.

Comment: If your browser is enforcing a CSP policy and there’s content that violates that policy, the browser will alway log an error message in the devtools console saying so. So if you don’t see any error message in the devtools console, then that means there’s no CSP violation.

Comment: After fiddling with the CSP values quite a bit, I was finally able to see a warning in DevTools: "Resource violated directive style-src…" The line it complains about looks like this: "<style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">@import "TemplatePackage/css/B/base-float.css"/**/;</style>" … This is not considered an inline style, is it? In any case, how to allow this without the unsafe-inline option?